# How do I get my app to request for permission?

Tags: android, android-studio, location, runtime, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to get my app to be able to ask for permissions when a user clicks the request permission button (btRequest). I don't have a problem when building the app but when running it on my phone my app stops. Check permission request works just fine since when I click btCheck I'm able to get a result. What could be the problem with trying to request for permissions?

[Logcat file](https://gist.github.com/maggz69/afaf1e03c4db2361e3eb6c77bbd23066)

```
private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Button btRequest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btRequest);
    Button btCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btCheck);
    btRequest.setOnClickListener(this);
    btCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    view = v;

    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.btCheck:
            if (checkPermission()) {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission already granted.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Please request permission.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btRequest:
            if (!checkPermission()) {

                requestPermission();

            } else {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission already granted.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}

private void requestPermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

        Toast.makeText(context,"GPS permission allows us to access location data." +
                " Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check build OS version (no need to ask permission for your OS version<23)

Step 1: (Check OS version)

```
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) 
    {
        checkAndRequestPermissions();
    }
```

Step 2: (Asking permission)

```
private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() 
{
    int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int storagePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (storagePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),permsRequestCode);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Step 3:  (Override method implementation)

```
     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 200: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                        waitAndNavigateToOnboardingTutorial();
                    } else {
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showDialogOK("Camera, Storage and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Step 4:

```
 private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with using

```
 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

instead of

```
 ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

It fixed it for me when I had a similar issue.

It's really hard to tell without your logcat contents. Try to tell us what exactly happens. I will edit this answer if necessary.

Comment: [View logcat file](https://gist.github.com/maggz69/afaf1e03c4db2361e3eb6c77bbd23066#file-logcat)

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean requestPermission() {
    int hasLocationPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (hasLocationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            showMessageOKCancel(getResources().getString(R.string.phone_permission_needed),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which) {
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                            REQUEST_CODE_SOME_FEATURES_PERMISSIONS);
                                    break;
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                    errorMessage.setText("Permissions not provided or permanently denied earlier.");
                                    providePermissions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            return false;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_CODE_SOME_FEATURES_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

One thing I noticed wrong in your code was you were only asking permission when "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale" condition was false. You have to ask for permissions anyways. This is a working code. You can try this out.